# Determine languages per user in Django Admin using django-modeltranslation

Tags: django, django-modeltranslation

I'm considering to use `django-modeltranslation` for my project. So far, seems very suitable.

One question about it, I'd like to create a custom method to determine what languages should be displayed and editable in the Admin based on the logged in user. Simple example of the method below:

```
def get_languages(user: User) -> list[str]:
    if user == Bert:
      return ['en']
    elif user == Ernie:
      return ['en', 'nl']
    return ['de']
```

Is this supported?